# How can I set custom widhts for my menu dropdowns in Woo Canvas so they match the width of the main tab?

Tags: css, menu, dropdown

How can I set custom widths for my menu dropdowns in Woo Canvas so they match the width of the main tab?
My test site is at http://www.fopm.co.uk/eds

The tabs that aren't right are Printing Services and Contact Us

Thanks

Comment: better to start with some of your own code here...so we can help you. SO is not free coding service

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css:

```
.sub-menu {
    width: 100% !important;  /* Don't forget to add !important */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a start:

```
ul#main-nav > li.menu-item{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 177px;

}
```